# Send a mail with an attachment on my hard drive with Apache commons email

Tags: java-8, apache-commons-email

I have a problem to send an attachment in my mail with Apache commons email.
To explain it quick and dirty, the mail is sent but there is no attachment at all when i look at it in Outlook.

I use Apache commons email v1.4 and JAVA 8.
I want to add a log file which is on my hard drive at this location C:\myfolder\myfile.log

This is what i have tried so far to add the attachment

```
Path logRejetPath = Paths.get("C:\\myfolder\\myfile.log");
Boolean pathExists = Files.exists(logRejetPath, new LinkOption[]{LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS});

if (pathExists) {
   File rejLogFile = new File(logRejetPath.toString());
   email.attach(new FileDataSource(rejLogFile), "test", "test");                
}
email.send();
```

Or

```
Path logRejetPath = Paths.get("C:\\myfolder\\myfile.log");
Boolean pathExists = Files.exists(logRejetPath, new LinkOption[]{LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS});

if (pathExists) {
   File rejLogFile = new File(logRejetPath.toString());
   email.attach(rejLogFile);                
}
email.send();
```

Or

```
Path logRejetPath = Paths.get("C:\\myfolder\\myfile.log");
Boolean pathExists = Files.exists(logRejetPath, new LinkOption[]{LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS});

if (pathExists) {
    EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
    attachment.setPath(logRejetPath.toString());
    attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
    attachment.setDescription("test");
    attachment.setName("test");
    email.attach(attachment);              
}
email.send();
```

I precise email is a MultiPartEmail object created like this:

```
MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();

    try {
        email.setHostName(config.getSmtpHost()); 
        email.setSmtpPort(Integer.valueOf(config.getSmtpPort()));
        if (!config.getSmtpUser().isEmpty()) {
            email.setAuthenticator(
                    new DefaultAuthenticator(config.getSmtpUser(), config.getSmtpPwd()));
            email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
        } else {
            email.setSSLOnConnect(false);
        }
        email.setCharset("utf-8");
        email.setFrom("me@me.fr");
        email.setSubject("subjectforemail");
        email.setContent(this.getMessage(), "text/html");

        final String[] destinataires = config.getMailDestinataires().split(";");
        for (final String dest : destinataires) {
            email.addTo(dest);
        }
```

Every time with these different methods to add an attachment, i receive my email with the message but without the attachment. Every time, variable pathExists is TRUE and every times i have no error.

Thanks for your future answers and help.

EDIT : Solution found by changing this :

```
MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
```

by this :

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
```

Comment: Nicely asked question. Please add it as an answer `HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found by changing this :

```
MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
```

by this :

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
```